# Add value to array in database

Tags: mysql

I have a custom database in my WordPress site where I want to save multiple values to one row.

Let's say I have an entry:

- id: auto increment
- pageid: id of current page
- time: text (is an array created with implode)

Example:

```
id  pageid  time
1   1       121212,121314,121415
2   2       121212,121314
```

What I am trying to achieve is a way I can extend the "time" field. Every time the function goes off, I want a `timestamp` added to the existing values.

So it would look like this:

```
id  pageid  time
1   1       121212,121314,121415, 181920
2   2       121212,121314, 292929, 988339
```

What would be the best way to solve this and how?

```
function custom_setup_db(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = "customdb"; 
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      userid mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
      timestamparray text,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );    
}

function wp_install_data(){
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = 'customdb';
    $timestamparray = array();
    array_push($timestamparray, '121212', '131415', '121316');
    $timeofvisit = implode(",", $timeofvisit);

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'timeofvisit' => $timeofvisit,
            'userid' => '2'
        ) 
    );   
}
```

Comment: I believe the wpdb class should be your friend.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.  Pulling the row `$wpdb->get_row('query', output_type, row_offset);` and modify the array seems the way to go.

Comment: As written, there is really nothing specifically WordPress about the question. There are at least a handful of ways to stored data similar to what you are asking but they are all pretty much pure PHP/MySQL. Perhaps you could provide more context to the question or, even better, code?

Comment: I added some code above, but i really do not know how to achieve what i am trying to.

Comment: why push the values into an array? seems to make more sense to store each visit as a row, especially if you intend to do any meaningful querying on it.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking this to, but as this is supposed to be a multisite installation i was afraid that it would get out of hand due to the amount of visits

Comment: I just tried inserting every visit into a new row which actually works, but I am still afraid that the amount of data will grow out of hand and as there is no way to work with FOREIGN KEYS ind wordpress i am still trying to figure out what would be an appropriate solution to this problem.
Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your table does not have a `timeofvisit` column. The second value of `$wpdb->insert` expects column value pairs, [see here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_rows). Try

```
$wpdb->insert( 
    $table_name, 
    array( 
        'timestamparray' => $timeofvisit,
        'userid' => '2'
    ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not using [$wpdb->update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)? I mean, when you insert data using $wpdb->insert(), and make conditions

```
if(following_conditions){
       $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where);
}
```

and give comma after the latest data.

this is example of my update functions:

```
$wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'users', ['user_pass'=>$repeat_password], ['user_email'=>$_GET["req:em"]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to store a multiple data in to the database is WordPress default core functionality, using `maybe_serialize` we can store and retrieve data in particular format. Kindly go through this [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_serialize/).

Let me explain you as per your code.
After using `maybe_serialize` function, your code will look like this.

```
function wp_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = 'customdb';
    $timestamparray = array();
    array_push($timestamparray, '121212', '131415', '121316');
    //$timeofvisit = implode(",", $timeofvisit);

    // Update code start
    $timeofvisit = maybe_serialize($timestamparray);
    // Update code end

    $wpdb->insert( 
        $table_name, 
        array( 
            'timeofvisit' => $timeofvisit,
            'userid' => '2'
        ) 
    );   
}
```

In database, data should store look like that.

```
a:2:{i:1;s:12:"Hello World!";s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}
```

When you get this records from database, then you need to call `maybe_unserialize` function, and you will get an array of that data.

I hope this will help you.